# How to show contribution if I only work on my own projects

Tags: github

Here is my project https://github.com/dat-nguyen-2001/Muji
and I did commit to it regularly
but it turned out that there was no contribution counted
https://github.com/dat-nguyen-2001
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should create a new branch for features you want to implement. Committing to the default/master/main branch is not recommended.

1. Think of what you want to develop/fix/change.
2. Create a new branch for it.
3. Switch to new branch, make changes and commit.
4. Raise a Pull Request to merge feature branch to default branch.

Read this to know which actions are counted as contributions: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#contributions-that-are-counted

Comment: that seems weird since I only work on my own project and do not collaborate with anyone. Anyway I'll try that